# Why does the reflections library not work in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, annotations

I'm using org.reflections:reflections to find annotated classes on the classpath within a Spring Boot application. When running the app from the IDE, everything works fine. But when I build the FAT-JAR and run it directly, it can't find *some* classes. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```java
// packagePrefixes is an array of strings
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packagePrefixes, Scanners.TypesAnnotated);

for (Class<?> clazz : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Resource.BaseClass.class)) {
    // This works, it'll iterate through all classes annotated
    // with Resource.BaseClass
}

for (Class<?> clazz : reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Listener.class)) {
    // This doesn't work, it won't iterate through all classes
    // annotated with Listener
}
```

Both annotations are annotated with

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

I already tried using precise packages so that the library won't need to iterate recursively.

Does anyone know what the problem is here? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have updated the code example :). I mean that the first loop works, the second doesn't. So the call to `reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Listener.class)` returns an empty list.

Comment: Is the difference caused by which annotation you’re looking for or by which classes have the annotation?

Comment: Good point! It seems like the issue is the class having the annotation. I annotated a class with both annotations and I could see from the logs that it hasn't been detected at all. So I think there is some classpath issue with Spring, though I can't figure out what it is. I have classes in a different Maven module (and package) that are detected just well ...

Comment: This might be a class loader issue. Passing the class loaders to the constructor could help.

Comment: This worked! I added the class loader via a `ConfigurationBuilder` and it now scans the classes. Thanks a lot!